# ICSharpCode.TextEditor undo/redo state

Tags: c#, .net, undo-redo, icsharpcode, text-editor

I'm trying to implement undo/redo feature in my custom application that displays code using ICSharpCode.TextEditor.

TextEditor fully supports undo and redo. But unfortunately, the control is poorly documented. It's not clear how to detect change of the undo state, so the program can gray out and re-enable the undo and redo buttons on the toolbar.

Is there any suitable event I can subscribe to? Should I then use EnableUndo and EnableRedo properties?

Comment: Where are these EnableUndo and EnableRedo properties that you speak of?  I need to find a way to stop AvalonEdit from intercepting Ctrl-Z or trying to handle undo at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the `IDocument` being edited, not the `TextEditor`. Make sure that you are editing the document using the `IDocument` methods. You can group actions together using `IDocument.UndoStack.StartUndoGroup` and `IDocument.UndoStack.EndUndoGroup`. To see if there are undos possible, you can check if the `IDocument.UndoStack` is empty.